# Script Not Executing When Item Is Picked Up In Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The gun script is not executing when the gun is picked up.

The scripted that is attached to the gun is supposed to be executing but it is not. I have tried to use `Debug.log()` instead of the code in the gun script but it does not do anything. The gun script that I have used also worked before I implemented the Pick Up system.

Gun Script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class gunshoot : MonoBehaviour
{

    public int gunDamage = 1;                                            // Set the number of hitpoints that this gun will take away from shot objects with a health script
    public float fireRate = 0.25f;                                        // Number in seconds which controls how often the player can fire
    public float weaponRange = 50f;                                        // Distance in Unity units over which the player can fire
    public float hitForce = 100f;                                        // Amount of force which will be added to objects with a rigidbody shot by the player
    public Transform gunEnd;
    public float shootForce = 1000f;                                              // Holds a reference to the gun end object, marking the muzzle location of the gun

    private Camera fpsCam;                                                // Holds a reference to the first person camera
    private WaitForSeconds shotDuration = new WaitForSeconds(0.07f);    // WaitForSeconds object used by our ShotEffect coroutine, determines time laser line will remain visible
    private AudioSource gunAudio;                                        // Reference to the audio source which will play our shooting sound effect
                                     // Reference to the LineRenderer component which will display our laserline
    private float nextFire;                                                // Float to store the time the player will be allowed to fire again, after firing


    void Start()
    {
        // Get and store a reference to our LineRenderer component


        // Get and store a reference to our AudioSource component
        gunAudio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();

        // Get and store a reference to our Camera by searching this GameObject and its parents
        fpsCam = GetComponentInParent<Camera>();
    }


    void Update()
    {
        // Check if the player has pressed the fire button and if enough time has elapsed since they last fired
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") && Time.time > nextFire)
        {
            // Update the time when our player can fire next
            nextFire = Time.time + fireRate;

            // Start our ShotEffect coroutine to turn our laser line on and off
            StartCoroutine(ShotEffect());

            // Create a vector at the center of our camera's viewport
            Vector3 rayOrigin = fpsCam.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f));

            // Declare a raycast hit to store information about what our raycast has hit
            RaycastHit hit;

            // Set the start position for our visual effect for our laser to the position of gunEnd


            // Check if our raycast has hit anything
            if (Physics.Raycast(rayOrigin, fpsCam.transform.forward, out hit, weaponRange))
            {
                // Set the end position for our laser line 


                // Get a reference to a health script attached to the collider we hit
                box health = hit.collider.GetComponent<box>();

                // If there was a health script attached
                if (health != null)
                {
                    // Call the damage function of that script, passing in our gunDamage variable
                    health.Damage(gunDamage);
                }

                // Check if the object we hit has a rigidbody attached
                if (hit.rigidbody != null)
                {
                    // Add force to the rigidbody we hit, in the direction from which it was hit
                    hit.rigidbody.AddForce(-hit.normal * hitForce);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // If we did not hit anything, set the end of the line to a position directly in front of the camera at the distance of weaponRange

            }
        }
    }


    private IEnumerator ShotEffect()
    {
        // Play the shooting sound effect
        gunAudio.Play();

        // Turn on our line renderer


        //Wait for .07 seconds
        yield return shotDuration;

        // Deactivate our line renderer after waiting

    }
}
```

Pick Up Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.Collections.LowLevel.Unsafe;
using UnityEngine;

public class pickUp : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject itemRefDup;
    public GameObject itemRef;
    public Transform inventory;
    public bool equiped = false;

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Player")
        {
            Debug.Log("it works");
            Destroy(itemRef);
            Instantiate(itemRefDup, inventory, inventory);
            equiped = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is supposed to happen and what is happening

Comment: it is suppose to execute the gun script

Comment: well by default that script only assigns a couple of variables, and if it doesnt find what its looking for it will look like it hasnt..  I guess you need to do more debugging

Comment: lol never mind just fixed it